# Error in calling php file in table data using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have small project in which i have different news.I have to include this news_all.php file in table data in the dashboard.php file. I have predefined root structure in which i cannot use include('news.php) and i dont want to use it. So in this case how i can be able to call news.php file in this table data in dashboard.php file.I have used Ajax method.I am almost done but having small mistake in my code.Any help.Thanks.
 Here is my code:

dashboard.php

```
   <?php
// -- REGISTER ERSTELLEN -------------------------------------------------------

$page['register-news'] = array(
    1   => array( 'News','aktiv',$page['script'],'',''),
);

$page['edit-register-news'] = array(
    1   => array( 'Edit-News','aktiv',$page['script'],'',''),
);


$page['content'] .= '

<table width="538" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" >
    <tr>
        <td id="News">
            <div>'.CreateRegister($page['register-news']).'</div>
            '.CreateMessage().'
            <div class="cont-liste-verlauf register">           


            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>';


?>
```

news_all.php

```
        <?php
include 'constant/const_system.inc.php';
include 'functions/ad_json.inc';
include 'functions/ad_formulare.inc';
$html = 
'<table width="538" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
<td>

<a href="news.php?id=" class="TrackNews" id="01">
<div class="welcome-rahmen lng toggleNews" id="news_269_kurz">
<p class="welcome-breadcrump">Montag, 19.05.2014</p>
<p class="welcome-subheadline">Teilnahme von MAN Top Used an der Samoter 2014</p>
<div class="newsText">
<p class="welcome-text"><img src="http://intern.autodo.de/admin/news/man-it.jpg" width="165" class="text_fixed" border="0"></p>
<p class="welcome-text">Die 29. Internationale Erd- und Bautechnik-Ausstellung Samoter fand zwischen dem 8. und 11. Mai in Verona statt und zog rund 100.000 Besucher an. Samoter ist die wichtigste italienische Messe ihrer Art, die den Themen Erdbewegung, Hochbau und Baumaschinen gewidmet ist. Zugleich ist diese Veranstaltung damit auch f? europ?chen Markt bedeutsam.</p>
</div>
</div>
</a>

<a href="news.php?id=" class="TrackNews" id="02">
<div class="welcome-rahmen lng toggleNews" id="news_264_kurz">
<p class="welcome-breadcrump">Freitag, 24.01.2014</p>
<p class="welcome-subheadline">Kaufvertrag: neue Porsche-Vorlage zum Drucken!</p>
<div class="newsText">
<img src="http://intern.autodo.de/admin/news/porsche-kaufvertrag.jpg" border="0" align="right" class="img_fixed" width=60><p class="welcome-text">Ihr AMO Druckcenter bietet Ihnen ab sofort die M?chkeit, Kaufvertr? im Porsche-Design zu nutzen.</p>
<p class="page-breadcrump">AutoDo!-Team</p>
</div>
</div>
</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>';
$return = array(
        'status' => 1,
        'html'  => $html
    );

    echo(json_encode($return)) ;

?>
```

ajax.js

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "news_all.php",
              dataType : 'json',
              cache: false,
              data: {},
              success: function(data){
                 $('#news').html(data.html);
              }
            });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there, 2 main things since you are using `data.html`

- `dataType : 'json'` (in the AJAX call)

  - This tell your AJAX function to treat the data received as a JSON object allowing you to use `data.html` (see more [jQuery.ajax() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/))
- `echo(json_encode($return))` (in the news_all.php output)

  - This gives the output in JSON compatible format

My Sample Codes below

dashboard.php

```
<table width="538" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" >
    <tr>
        <td id="news">
            <div>'.CreateRegister($page['register-news']).'</div>
            '.CreateMessage().'
            <div class="cont-liste-verlauf register">           


            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "news_all.php",
          dataType : 'json',
          cache: false,
          data: {},
          success: function(data){
             $('#news').html(data.html);
          }
        });

</script>
```

news_all.php

```
<?php
$html =' <table width="538" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
    <td>    
    <a href="news.php?id=" class="TrackNews" id="01">
        <div class="welcome-rahmen lng toggleNews" id="news_269_kurz">
        <p class="welcome-breadcrump">Montag, 19.05.2014</p>
        <p class="welcome-subheadline">Teilnahme von MAN Top Used an der Samoter 2014</p>
        <div class="newsText">
        <p class="welcome-text"><img src="http://intern.autodo.de/admin/news/man-it.jpg" width="165" class="text_fixed" border="0"></p>
        <p class="welcome-text">Die 29. Internationale Erd- und Bautechnik-Ausstellung Samoter fand zwischen dem 8. und 11. Mai in Verona statt und zog rund 100.000 Besucher an. Samoter ist die wichtigste italienische Messe ihrer Art, die den Themen Erdbewegung, Hochbau und Baumaschinen gewidmet ist. Zugleich ist diese Veranstaltung damit auch f? europ?chen Markt bedeutsam.</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        </a>

        <a href="news.php?id=" class="TrackNews" id="02">
        <div class="welcome-rahmen lng toggleNews" id="news_264_kurz">
        <p class="welcome-breadcrump">Freitag, 24.01.2014</p>
        <p class="welcome-subheadline">Kaufvertrag: neue Porsche-Vorlage zum Drucken!</p>
        <div class="newsText">
        <img src="http://intern.autodo.de/admin/news/porsche-kaufvertrag.jpg" border="0" align="right" class="img_fixed" width=60><p class="welcome-text">Ihr AMO Druckcenter bietet Ihnen ab sofort die M?chkeit, Kaufvertr? im Porsche-Design zu nutzen.</p>
        <p class="page-breadcrump">AutoDo!-Team</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        </a>

        <a href="news.php?id=" class="TrackNews" id="03">
        <div class="welcome-rahmen lng toggleNews" id="news_265_kurz">
        <p class="welcome-breadcrump">Mittwoch, 15.01.2014</p>
        <p class="welcome-subheadline">AutoDo! Update: Die Eigenschaft -Unfallfahrzeug- wurde im AMO erweitert!</p>
        <div class="newsText">
        <p class="welcome-text">Ab sofort k?n Sie Fahrzeuge nach folgenden Kriterien kennzeichnen:</p>
        <p class="highlight"><b>? Unfallfahrzeug<br>
        ? Unfallfrei<br>
        ? Keine Angabe</b></p>
        <p class="page-breadcrump">AutoDo!-Team</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        </a>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
';
$return = array(
        'status' => 1,
        'html'  => $html
    );

    echo(json_encode($return)) ;

?>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have made the changes you told me but its not giving any error not showing any output.I have checked in the firebug.Please check the changes in the question.Thank you.

Comment: I am almost done but having small mistake in my code :(

Comment: You're not supposed to have html <script> tags in your Javascript (.js) file